# Excel: how to load multiple formulas back to a range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, range

Most people know that you should calculate all the numbers in VBA and load them all in Excel at once to reduce the number of spreadsheet access and increase the speed.  Typically Range("a1:a10") = myArray.

Well, I want to do this, but for formulas instead of values.

```
Sub myTest()
  Dim myFormulas() As String
  ReDim myFormulas(1 To 5)

  myFormulas(1) = "Abc"
  myFormulas(2) = "Ac"
  myFormulas(3) = "Ab"
  myFormulas(4) = "bc"
  myFormulas(5) = "=A1"

  Range("F232:J232").Formula = myFormulas
End Sub
```

This "almost works". In J232, it shows text =A1 instead of the value of A1. I then need to go into the formula and press enter for the =A1 to then convert into the value of A1.

Has anyone experienced this before? any fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you set it to be a string, try this:

```
Sub myTest()
    Dim myFormulas() As Variant
    myFormulas = Array("Abc", "Ac", "Ab", "bc", "=A1")
    Range("F232").Resize(1, UBound(myFormulas) + 1).Formula = myFormulas
End Sub
```

Also made it more dynamic using resize to work off the size of the array rather than a static range